# C++ Write variables of all inheriting classes constructors at once into the file

Tags: c++, file, class, save, load

Ok, I have three classes `A`, `B` and `C`, while both `B` and `C` are inheriting `A` but not each other. And I want while creating, if I put any other values, to save them into the file. All three classes has `const char* name` to recognize what is it and what it should contains, so it must save 1st in any of `A`, `B` or `C` and look something like this:

```
name=Atest b=10\n
name=B b=0 q=10 x=20\n
name=C b=0 g=30\n
```

But, when I tried it, only last created class is writen in file, and only it's variable:
`g=30`

**class A**

```
class A {
public:
    const char* name;
    short b;
    A() { this->name = "A"; this->b = 0; }
    A(const char* name, short b) : A() {
        this->b = b; this->name = name;
        std::ofstream savefl;
        savefl.open("saves.txt");
        savefl << "name=" << this->name << " b=" << this->b << std::endl;
        savefl.close();
    }
};
```

**class B**

```
class B : public A {
public:
    short q, x;
    B() : A() {
        this->name = "B"; this->q = this->x = 0;
    }
    B(short q, short x) : B() {
        this->q = q; this->x = x;
        std::ofstream savefl;
        savefl.open("saves.txt");
        savefl << "q=" << this->q << " x=" << this->x << std::endl;
        savefl.close();
    }
};
```

**class C**

```
class C : public A {
public:
    short g;
    C() : A() {
        this->name = "C"; this->g = 0;
    }
    C(short g) : C() {
        this->g = g;
        std::ofstream savefl;
        savefl.open("saves.txt");
        savefl << "g=" << this->g << std::endl;
        savefl.close();
    }
};
```

**main**

```
    A a("Atest", 10);
    B b(10, 20);
    C c(30);
```

Comment: Probably better to open the file once, and pass in the `std::ofstream&`, rather than opening and reopening the file over and over.  Especially since the `mode` of the file being opened probably isn't the `mode` you want.

Answer (score 0):

the file "saves.txt" was opened 3 times as ofstream, each time the file will be truncated to blank.

```
 savefl.open("saves.txt", ios::app);
```

this line of code might be what you want.